# Why rake task output always ends with test-unit like result?

Tags: ruby, rake

Since some time ago all output of all rake tasks I run has test/unit-like result in the end:

```
Finished in 0.002001 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

It is shown even if I run `rake --tasks`.

Comment: Can you put the content of the rakefile you are running?

Comment: Thank you, Danny, you pointed me to an answer. I had `require 'test/unit'` in one of my rake files. When I moved it inside the task body it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `require 'test/unit'` on top of one of my rake files.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, according to the comments.

> Thank you, Danny, you pointed me to an answer. I had require
>   'test/unit' in one of my rake files. When I moved it inside the task
>   body it is fixed.

For the benefit of future googlers, I'm not sure why you would want to require test unit within a rake file, rather than within the test file.

Comment: I wanted to do some assertions in the rake task. I agree this is not a good practice. I believe I later refactored it to be a subtask under test namespace.